# C# Cast FormData to an Object

Tags: c#, upload

I'm posting a file and a json object to my API using angularjs. I'm able to get all the data from the server (file and model object):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> send()
{
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    var modelFromClient = result.FormData["model"];
}
```

The modelFromClient i receive has this format : `"model":"{\"name\":\"James\",\"comments\":\"test\"}`

But i want to cast the **modelFromClient** json to my user model which is :

```
public User {
    public string name{ get; set; }   
    public string comments{ get; set; }
}
```

So at the end, i want to be able to get my attributes like i used to do when i send the object explicitly trought the url :

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> add(User user) {

  // here, my user object will have all the values that i set in my client side and i get them like this : 
    user.name;
    user.comments;
    ...// other attributes
    // Save the object in dataBase
    user.Save();
}
```

I hope you understand my need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of the client json, then perhaps you could omit the `model` field and just send the content like so:

```
{
    "name": "james",
    "comments": "test"
}
```

This would allow you to use your existing controller implementation "as-is".

If however, the client json is out of your control, then you need to deserialize it into a model that is representative of the json. Changing your model to the following would likely work:

```
public Model
{
    public User model { get; set; }
}
```

Because you are reading out the raw json from the request, you can deserialize it manually before calling add() directly

And then your controller would change to this (Assumes Json.Net is referenced):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> send()
{
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    var modelFromClient = result.FormData["model"];

    var clientModel = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Model>(modelFromClient);

    return await add(clientModel.user);
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> add(User user)
{
    //Do whatever you need with user

    //Save the object in database
    user.Save();
}
```

Comment: Since i'm uploading a file, the only way to get  the Data model is to use  result.FormData["model"] and use the function : public async Task<IHttpActionResult> send() without params.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include manual deserialization before calling `add` manually.

Comment: This is a good start ! yes i do have a control of the client json but i cannat omit to put an attribute when i append a object to the form data :  var formData= new FormData();formData.append("model",angular.toJson(data.model));
                formData.append("file", data.file); Maybe you have a another suggestion to remove the 'model' attribute?